# How do I get rid of this orange selection box?

Tags: selection-tools

[image: A screenshot of this.]

All i did was hit cntrl+b... Please help!

Comment: Press Ctrl+ Alt+ B

Answer (score 0):

Right Click out of it, or just do  Ctrl+ Alt+ B...

Comment: Right clicking will not remove render border.

Comment: @Mr_Zak it would if he was still selecting and didnt apply with leftclick

Comment: @HenrikD while yes, the question is about already applied border